# Redirect in httpd.conf is not working to specific pages of the ServerName

Tags: apache, tomcat, web, virtualhost

I'm trying to redirect all the old url to the new https one for my application.

an extract of my httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName foo.myapp.fr
    ServerAlias foo.myapp2.com
    Redirect permanent / https://foo.newurl.com/
    ProxyPass /foo/ ajp://localhost:8009/foo/
    ProxyPass /fows/ ajp://localhost:8009/foows/
</VirtualHost>
```

The redirect is working fine except when i go to a specific page.

Exemple :

foo.myapp.fr is redirecting to https://foo.newurl.com/

foo.myapp.fr/foo/jsp/index.jsp is not redirecting.

Did I make a mistake in the virtualhost configuration ?

Should i add a "ProxyPass /foo/jsp/ ajp://localhost:8009/foo/" ?

Thanks !
Arthur

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable ProxyPass for `/jsp` location. Otherwise it will intercept requests and redirect won't work.

Comment: sorry for the delay, i update my question with more information. Should i use something like "ProxyPass /foo/jsp ajp://localhost:8009/foo/" ?